# Ajax request: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax

I am using [this](http://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/) jQuery plugin to render a toggle button in a block. When the button is toggled off/on I want to write to a databse table (with `entity_save`). Here's the relevant code I'm using to try to acheive this:

```
// hook_menu item
$items['product-status-update'] = array(
  'title'=>'Status update',
  'page callback' => 'my_module_status_update',
  'access callback' => 'product_entity_access', 
  'type'=> MENU_CALLBACK,
);

// jQuery
drupal_add_js('
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      $(".toggle-button").toggles({' . $status . $state . '});
      $(".toggle-button").on("toggle", function (e, status) {
        status = status == true ? 1 : 0
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "?q=product-status-update",
          data: "pid="+' . $pid . '&"status="+status,
        });
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
', 'inline');

// Callback
function my_module_status_update() {
  $pid = $_POST['pid'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $product = entity_load_single('product', $pid);
  $product->status = $status;
  entity_save('product', $product);
}

// Console log output when toggling
POST http://example.com/?q=product-status-update 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
1 ?q=home:98
0 ?q=home:99
POST http://example.com/?q=product-status-update 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
1 ?q=home:98
1 ?q=home:99
POST http://example.com/?q=product-status-update 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
1 ?q=home:98
0 ?q=home:99
```

As you can see from the console log output I am receiving: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Any ideas why or what might be the culprit? Thanks.

Comment: Http 500 really means: check error logs. Have you seen them? what's there? Both in your webserver's error.log and Drupal's watchdog.

Comment: Thanks. I have a database query error in watchdog. I was looking for a js/server error, not a Drupal-php error. Looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Put that database query error in your question if you can't fix it by yourself. Or consider posting self-answer about proper logs and final solution.

Comment: My database query was failing because `entity_load_single` is returning false - because $_POST, and therefore $pid, is empty. So I gues my issue is with my implementation of `$.ajax` in my jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was:

```
data: "pid="+' . $pid . '&"status="+status,
```

should be

```
data: "&pid=" + ' . $pid . ' + "&status=" + status,
```

Seems obvious now.

Anyway, the above is the basics of how to update a value in the database by sliding a jQuery toggle button back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, there's some issues with the code, however, the main error may be:

```
$product = entity_load_single('product', $pid);
```

where you don't have a `$pid` value, you're setting `$fid` instead.

```
$fid = $_POST['pid'];
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, but I've identified the problem: $_POST is empty.